# How to halt the invocation of the mapper or reducer

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I am trying to run my hadoop map/reduce job inside eclipse (not a node and or cluster) to debug my map/reduce logic. I want to able to put a break point on the mapper and reducer and make eclipse to stop on these break points however this is not happening and the things mapper get stuck. I noticed that if I hit suspend and run a couple of times, it will eventually break on the mapper and reducer. I am very new to eclipse. What am doing wrong?

I am literally running the word count code at http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount and have break points on lines 22, 35.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have disabled break points? The break points will be displayed with a strike through icon if that is the case.

When not running locally it is possible that your break points will not be hit, because the tasks are run in new isolated JVMs. However that does not seem to be the case here, because `suspend` would not work either in that case.

Comment: As you mentioned, the break points are enabled and I am running locally. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Well I tried your example and it works fine for me. What you could try now is setting a break point in your main method. If the debugger does not stop there either you have a general, not hadoop related problem.

Comment: Actually it does stop in the main method. At least, I know this is not the typical behavior. Thanks